# YUI Datatable Blocks Enter Event of Other Components At A Page

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui-datatable

I have a problem with selecting an option from combobox through hitting enter. Two pages are exist, one of these page uses YUI data table, while the other one does not. I have this problem only at the page with YUI datatable. After some digging, I am sure YUI data table causes a problem about enter key events of all other components at the page. If I remove YUI data table from the page, it works without any problem.

I’m using datatable-beta.js for yui-data table and we cannot replace it with a newer version. There are so many things relates to this library, so it is not wanted by the company.

I cannot use enter to select an option at a simple “html select tag” because of this problem.

How do we solve this problem? Does someone face with a similar problem about YI library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the method in your page so that you won't need to change the original script.

Just override it like below (e.keyCode==13 removed) and your enter issue for that page will be solved.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
YAHOO.widget.DataTable.prototype._onDocumentKeydown=function(e,oSelf)
{
  if((e.keyCode==27))
  {
        oSelf.cancelEditorData();
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Pretty good idea, I did not touch anywhere else. I just overrided that page. It works now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I commented out some code blocks to find out which code causes this problem. I eliminated lots of code parts by this way and reached this line:

```
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(document,"keydown",this._onDocumentKeydown,this);
```

This line is at the datatable-beta.js and I don't know why they did something like this. They're handling keydown event of all dom element. That's why I cannot hit the enter to select an option from combobox. Combobox is just a sample, I mean we cannot use enter for any component at the page. Handler method's code is below:

```
YAHOO.widget.DataTable.prototype._onDocumentKeydown=function(e,oSelf)
{
      if((e.keyCode==27))
      {
            oSelf.cancelEditorData();
      }
      if(e.keyCode==13)
      {
            YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent(e);
            oSelf.saveEditorData();
      }
}
```

They're handling escape and enter characters. I do not want to comment out these lines. It may effect other code blocks. I found the problem exactly, but you may still suggest a solution. Because, even if i found the problem, I'm still searching the best way to use enter key without changing orginal script.